# What does a decision tree hypothesis look like?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

I am learning [Tom M. Mitchell. Machine Learning (free)](http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~monsefi/machine-learning/pdf/Machine-Learning-Tom-Mitchell.pdf).

in Candidate-Elimination algorithm, a single hypothesis looks like $<Sunny, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?>$

there are three hypotheses in FIGURE 2.1 in that book, in which $h_1$ and $h_2$ are 2 different hypotheses.

[image]

similarly, what does a single hypothesis learned by decision tree regarding discrete dataset look like? is the following one a single hypothesis?

[image]